# What is the difference between <strong> and <em> tags?

Tags: html, xhtml, semantics

Both of them emphasize text. The `<em>` tag shows text as italics, whereas `<strong>` makes it bold. Is this the only difference?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yeah, the definition of what ‘strong emphasis’ is compared to just ‘emphasis’ is pretty woolly. The only **standard definition** would be “it's *emphasised*, but *more*!!”.

Personally I use `<em>` for normal emphasis where you'd read the emphasised word in a different tone of voice, and `<strong>` for that thing where you take **key words and phrases** to pick them out of the text to help people skimming the text pick out the subjects.

This isn't a standard interpretation, but it makes some sense and rendered appropriately by the default italic/bold styles. Whatever you do, **be consistent**.

Comment: u wrote "....different tone of voice" it means the differencce is only related to screen reader not for screens. Should we style <strong> as bold text and <em> as italic text, always?

Comment: Nah, style them how you like, but the usage of bold for skimwords (as they stand out) and italic for emphasised words (which don't) is pretty commonplace. As for tone of voice what I really mean is the tone of voice you'd read it in out loud (or in your head), rather than specifically anything to do with screen readers (though they could do it too).

Comment: It's nicely described and labeled here (http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/em.html) as /local/ versus /global/ emphasis.

Comment: While, as bobince points out, there's no clear distinction, his interpretation is in keeping with the literary convention, i.e., italics is typically used to convey emphasis when reading. There's no particular literary convention for bold text; in a web context where skimming is typical, it makes sense to use bold for key words/phrases as bobince mentions. And while semantics are important, it's ok to just use CSS to apply bold/italic, e.g., `<div>Lorem <span class="bold">ipsum</span> <span class="italic">dolor</span></div>`.

Comment: @Rabarberski that page has *by far* the clearest explanation I have ever heard: _The best approach is probably to treat em as “local” emphasis, which should be indicated when the text is read but need not jump on the reader’s face, whereas strong is for “global” emphasis, which is roughly the opposite: text marked up using strong should be prominently highlighted, but usually not emphasized when actually reading the text_ - perfect!

Answer (score 19):

<strong> is a tag you'd put around a sentence or phrase to indicate that "this is more important than the surrounding text".

<em> is generally used to indicate the stress of a word within a sentence.

For example:

> In spite of what some might say, there *is* a semantic difference between the elements.

For a clear distinction between stress emphasis and importance, and more examples, [see the HTML 5 draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element).

Comment: There is nothing in the spec about one applying to words and the other to phrases.

Comment: The words and phrases distinction is incidental to my answer.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, as you're not just stating a spec but  giving a bit more insight to what the two really mean.

Comment: The words and phrases distinction does not seem incidental to this answer. I see almost no other content in this answer (other than an external link). If the point is something else, the answer should make that clear. Is the point to distinguish “more important” from “stress”? I see no difference between those. As far as I know, “stress” is used to refer to ways of indicating importance.

Answer (score 8):

From the WHATWG's [Living standard HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-em-element):

> ## The `em` element
>
> The `em` element represents stress emphasis of its contents.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The placement of stress emphasis changes the meaning of the sentence. The element thus forms an integral part of the content. The precise way in which stress is used in this way depends on the language.
>
> ---
>
> **Example**
>
> These examples show how changing the stress emphasis changes the meaning. First, a general statement of fact, with no stress:
>
> ```
> Cats are cute animals.
> ```
>
> By emphasizing the first word, the statement implies that the kind of animal under discussion is in question (maybe someone is asserting that dogs are cute):
>
> ```
> <p><em>Cats</em> are cute animals.</p>
> ```
>
> Moving the stress to the verb, one highlights that the truth of the entire sentence is in question (maybe someone is saying cats are not cute):
>
> ```
> <p>Cats <em>are</em> cute animals.</p>
> ```
>
> By moving it to the adjective, the exact nature of the cats is reasserted (maybe someone suggested cats were mean animals):
>
> ```
> <p>Cats are <em>cute</em> animals.</p>
> ```
>
> Similarly, if someone asserted that cats were vegetables, someone correcting this might emphasise the last word:
>
> ```
> <p>Cats are cute <em>animals</em>.</p>
> ```
>
> By emphasizing the entire sentence, it becomes clear that the speaker is fighting hard to get the point across. This kind of stress emphasis also typically affects the punctuation, hence the exclamation mark here.
>
> ```
> <p><em>Cats are cute animals!</em></p>
> ```
>
> Anger mixed with emphasizing the cuteness could lead to markup such as:
>
> ```
> <p><em>Cats are <em>cute</em> animals!</em></p>
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Note**
>
> *[...]*
>
> The `em` element *[...]* isn't intended to convey importance; for that purpose, the `strong` element is more appropriate.
>
> ---
>
> *[...]*
>
> ## The `strong` element
>
> The `strong` element represents strong importance, seriousness, or urgency for its contents.
> *[...]*
> In this example, the `strong` element is used to denote the part of the text that the user is intended to read first.
>
> ```
> <p>Welcome to Remy, the reminder system.</p>
> <p>Your tasks for today:</p>
> <ul>
>  <li><p><strong>Turn off the oven.</strong></p></li>
>  <li><p>Put out the trash.</p></li>
>  <li><p>Do the laundry.</p></li>
> </ul>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

In HTML4:

EM indicates emphasis.

STRONG: Indicates stronger emphasis.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1

Comment: of text content surrounded by those tags

Comment: It's a semantic thing. You decide that that bit of text needs more emphasis, so you tag it with <em>.

Comment: I found info on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29 but it only say it's different styled of text

Comment: That article is talking about typography, not HTML. Don't get hung up on the way that it looks (by default, in most graphical browsers, before CSS is applied)

Comment: I like to think of it as the difference between "*You* didn't go to the store" and "**Do not** go near the buzzsaw". They both have emphasis, but one is quite a bit stronger.

Comment: You need to check the HTML5 draft, which more clearly indicates the distinction between stress emphasis and importance.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [**the difference is going to change**](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_phrase_elements.asp):

> In HTML 4.01, the `<strong>` tag defined
>   strong emphasized text, but in HTML 5
>   it defines important text.

Doesn't make the issue any clearer, does it?

Comment: Not much. But the examples in the HTML 5 draft make the distinction clearer.

Comment: Might change. It is still a draft.

Answer (score 1):

`em`: Indicates emphasis.

`strong`: Indicates stronger emphasis.

Its effect in user accessibility tool (NVDA).

Its also effect in SEO.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1